# Vote-to-close reasons

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I never exercise my vtc

And then [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/65930/37256) came along and I did.

And was disappointed to find no reason strong enough – I wanted to say "Because you're bullshitting". Evidently you cant.

Actually @Conifold did come close to saying this in [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/65932/37256)

So registering my request for tougher (more differentiated) vtcs.

---

## Added later

Seriously : If "spam" is good enough reason for closing why not "troll"?

Comment: Perfect, I am glad I wasn't the only one to notice it! I hope the mods take some tough action! Regards

Comment: Your question isn't even a question, except for the "**Added later**" part...

Comment: Changed the tag @andrewkoster to make it clear

Comment: @Rusi, some persistent trolls lol! Look at Koster's comment here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65930/is-right-and-wrong-the-only-thing-that-matters

Comment: `AngelIntegrity: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.` Literally no posts with any upvotes, on any of the sites...